# Give [dual-boot] the boot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There are a [handful of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) tagged [dual-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) on Stack Overflow and all of these are about troubleshooting dual-boot or multi-boot configurations.  None of these questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow and I cannot foresee any usage of this tag that is on-topic. The closest thing I can think of is for designing a [bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootloader), but we have a tag for that already.

Comment: Suggested title: Giving [dual-boot] the boot.

Comment: Just went through and voted to close and delete the ones that I believe are off-topic.  Please don't just go and remove the tag, keep the tag so other users can find (and close) these questions easily.

Comment: Yeah, you seriously missed a title pun golden opportunity here.

Comment: Give it the dual boot!

Comment: @deceze A dual boot to the head?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All of the questions that were in that tag were on hold. Myself and a few other users have manually deleted them all. After 24 hours as long as no new question is posted the tag will automatically be removed from the system when the cleanup process runs.

Comment: They were all put on hold by users who read this question.  Thanks!

Comment: @GovindParmar No problem.  The really small tags a breeze to go through.

Comment: @NathanOliver First the answer, now the comment... does your computer autodelete words? :-P

Comment: @TylerH I would love to blame the computer but unfortunately the problem lies with my fingers being faster then my brain.